# New to JMeter - How do I know if my scripts are hitting the application correctly?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to JMeter, but I know this is a very broad question...

I'm just trying to understand ways to see if my scripts are actually following the correct workflow I want it to and is hitting all the points it needs to be as accurate as possible?

I may be over-complicating and looking for answers that aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your [JMeter test script generates the same network footprint as the real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

The options I can think of are:

1. Cross-check the requests which are being sent by JMeter and by the real browser using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener on JMeter side and "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) on the other side.
2. Use a 3rd-party [sniffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture requests from JMeter and from the real browser and compare them. Requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))